# Is there an R function to make a new columns in different data tables?

Tags: r, function

I have a data frame, DT. It is split into different tables by one variable.

```
DT <- data.table (A=c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,5), B=c(200,210,300,420,289,365,587,250,110,500,800), C=c(0.6,0.35,0.6,0.85,0.22,0.36,0.39,0.31,0.33,0.58,0.66))
DT_Split <- split(DT, DT$A)
Table1<- DT_Split$`1`
Table2<- DT_Split$`2`
Table3<- DT_Split$`3`
Table4<- DT_Split$`4`
Table5<- DT_Split$`5`
```

Therefore I have 5 tables that came from DT.
I want to add one column, GH in each table by using a function.
Is there an R function that I can use?
So, if I have 10 tables with another data frame, then I can use this function without adding manually for each table.

Thanks in advance,
Milad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to operate on list of dataframes you can use `lapply`. For example, if you want to add a new column (named `new_column`) in each element of the list with a value (`new_value`) you can do

```
lapply(DT_Split, function(x) {
  x$new_column <- 'new_value'
  x
}) -> DT_new
```

In this way you can do multiple things on each dataframe in the list without doing it on each one manually.

---

For a specific function mentioned by OP we can do :

```
lapply(DT_Split, function(x) {
  x[, B := cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(A) < 0))]
  x
}) -> DT_new
```

Or since this is a grouped operation we can also perform this first by group and then split.

```
DT[, B := cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(A) < 0)), A]
DT_Split <- split(DT, DT$A)
```

Comment: Thanks again for your helpful answers. If I want to make a new column with `DT[, B := cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(A) < 0))]` . How can I add it in this function? Thanks

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks, That's Great! I appreciate that!